# Passing values through map, javascript functional programming

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

I'm working on a set of functions to rotate 2D arrays:

```
[                     [
  [1,2,3],              [3, 6, 9],
  [4,5,6],      ->      [2, 5, 8],
  [7,8,9],              [1, 4, 7],
 ]                     ]
```

For fun, I'm trying to rigorously follow functional programming principles.

The problem is currently solved like this:

```js
const get = id => array => array[id]
const compose = (a, b) => x => a(b(x));

const reverse = array => [...array].reverse();

const map = fn => array => array.map(fn);

const pluck = index => map(get(index));

// Create a 0-indexed range from an array.
// eg. ['a', 'b', 'c'] -> [0, 1, 2]
const rangeFrom = ({length}) => [...Array(length).keys()];

// Flip the matrix across its bottom-left to top-right axis
//   [1,2]    ->    [4,2]
//   [3,4]          [3,1]
const flipMatrix = matrix => (
  map(index => pluck(index)(matrix))(rangeFrom(matrix))
);

// Rotate the matrix clockwise
//   [1,2]    ->    [3,1]
//   [3,4]          [4,2]
const rotateMatrix = compose(flipMatrix, reverse);

// Flip the matrix across its top-left to bottom-right axis
//   [1,2]    ->    [1,3]
//   [3,4]          [2,4]
const flipMatrixCounterClockwise = compose(reverse, rotateMatrix);

// Rotate the matrix counter-clockwise
//   [1,2]    ->    [2,4]
//   [3,4]          [1,3]
const rotateMatrixCounterClockwise = compose(reverse, flipMatrix);



////// Sample code
const sampleMatrix = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
];
  
console.log("Matrix:", sampleMatrix);

console.log("Flip Matrix:", flipMatrix(sampleMatrix));
console.log("Rotate Matrix:", rotateMatrix(sampleMatrix));
console.log("Flip Matrix counter-clockwise:", flipMatrixCounterClockwise(sampleMatrix));
console.log("Rotate Matrix counter-clockwise:", rotateMatrixCounterClockwise(sampleMatrix));
```

The way it works is I create a range for the number of columns in the matrix, and map through the range. For each range number (which is really just a column index), I create a new row in the matrix made up of one of the columns.

In the simplest example, I start by grabbing the first item from every row, and turning *that* into my first row:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]

 ^
 └ On first run, take 1, 4, and 7, and make that the first row.
   Continue turning columns into rows:
   [1,4,7]
   [2,5,8]
   [3,6,9]
```

My issue with this solution is with the `flipMatrix` method. I'm mapping through a specific *row*, not the matrix itself, so I have this `matrix` variable at the top that can't be passed into the `map` function.

(It's important to do it this way since it needs to work even in an asymmetrical grid, eg. 2x6, so I need to map through the columns, not the rows).

It seems like there should really be some nice way to make it point-free, so that I can just compose from its building blocks. Because I have to pass this variable "through" the map, the pieces aren't composable.

Is there some nice way I'm unfamiliar with to pass data "through" a map in a stateless way? I'm pretty new to functional programming so I'm wondering if there's some crucial hole in my knowledge.

Comment: I would recomend using `math.js` http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html

Comment: you're not using `this` in any of your functions, which can be really relay handy to slightly customize generic routines. it looks like your functional wheel re-inventions don't pass `this`, but they could easily be re-written so that they can, like, eg: `[1,2,3,4,5,15,16,17,18].map(/./.test, /[02468]$/)` or `function gt(n){"use strict";  return n > this; }`. that extra "arg" will let you pass/bind in the little bit of "config" it sounds like you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! @ZohaibIjaz that looks neat, and I may use it for a future project, but this is just a learning exercise for me where I see what native JS is capable of RE: functional programming.

Comment: @dandavis That could work, but I'm more looking for functional approaches for solving this kind of problem. I think the problem with `this` is that you can't write pure functions with it, since the same inputs won't always yield the same outputs. Appreciate the suggestion though :) It may be that there isn't a way to do what I'm thinking.

Comment: imho, `this` makes pure functions sane in JS. `this` is just an argument, not a closure, so this-using functions are still pure and transparent. i can't imagine any functional JS without `this`, shoot me. you can actually make cleaner more generic handlers using `this` than with the closure model you've implemented; ex. `index.map(pluck, matrix)` - fewer parens, more composable, more re-usable...